# Valid Wordpress html elements

Tags: wp-admin, html, content-restriction

I'm working a plug-in on the admin side of it. I would like to show a html listbox element on the form. But no matter what I try, it will only show 1 entry. It is scroll-able, which I want when it overflows. I am using the size attribute to set the size of the list. It shows up as a drop down. I'm wondering if there are some html elements that aren't valid in Wordpress? Is there a list someplace? Thanks

Comment: Could you share the code you've written and you're have problems with?

Comment: @AnttiKoskinen I tried to send the html originally and it being html didn't show. I couldn't figure out how to do it thus just my question. However here is a link to an example on w3schools that results in the same problem when inserted on an admin page. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, now I think I get what you're asking. I think you're looking for `multiple` attribute that can be added to the `select` element. Example, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp Is this what you we're after?

Comment: That got me the results that I wanted. Thank you and have a great day. PS - I should have gotten back to you much sooner. I got pulled away on a project that I wasn't expecting.